# remove duplicated pattern/entries within each field in CSV file

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl, unicode, csv-simple

How do I remove duplicated entries within each separate fields with below sample as data.

```
0x,9.4,,,#0,#UNIX#unix,#cli#L#فا#0#فا#0#L#SE#Cli#SE,#فارسی#فارسی#۱#1#١#1,bsh,#V & v
```

expected output(either delete all duplicated ones, case-insensitive, difference in Unicode "Persian `#۱`/Arabic `#١`", order of entries and which entry (ignore case) should keep doesn't matter here):

```
0x,9.4,,,#0,#unix,#cli#L#فا#0#SE,#فارسی#١#۱#1,bsh,#V & v
```

The pattern is in this format `#x`, `x` means anything in one or more length of characters.

[Unicode table for Persian/Arabic languages alphabet/numbers differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_alphabet#Differences_from_Arabic_alphabet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) command line in a shell (just a few lines) with a proper [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) parser :

```
perl -CS -Mopen=":std,IN,OUT,IO,:encoding(utf8)" -MText::CSV -lne '
    BEGIN{
        our $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => "," });
        sub uniq { my %seen;  grep !$seen{lc $_}++, @_; }
    };
    $csv->parse($_) or die "parse error";
    print join ",", map { join "#", uniq split /#/ } $csv->fields();
' file.csv
```

### Output :

```
0x,9.4,,,#0,#UNIX,#cli#L#فا#0#SE,#فارسی#۱#1#١,bsh,#V & v
```

### Note :

- require to install `Text::CSV` perl module : `sudo apt-get install libtext-csv-perl` for debian and derivative

Answer (score 1):

Complete **`Python`** solution:

**`uniq_arabic_csv.py`** script:

```
#!/bin/python

import sys, re

csv_data = sys.stdin.read().strip()
result = []

for item in csv_data.split(','):
    matches = list(re.finditer(r'#[^#]+', item, re.U | re.I))
    if not matches or len(matches) == 1:
        result.append(item)
    else:
        s, res = set(), []
        for m in matches:
            m = m.group()
            if m.lower() not in s: res.append(m)
            s.add(m.lower())
        result.append(''.join(res))

result = ','.join(result)                    
print(result)
```

---

Usage:

```
s="0x,9.4,,,#0,#UNIX#unix,#cli#L#فا#0#فا#0#L#SE#Cli#SE,#فارسی#فارسی#۱#1#۱#1,bsh,#V & v"
python uniq_arabic_csv.py <<<"$s"
```

The output:

```
0x,9.4,,,#0,#UNIX,#cli#L#فا#0#SE,#فارسی#۱#1,bsh,#V & v
```

Answer (score 0):

I code below simple `awk` solution as well:

```c
awk -F, '{ i=0; comma=""; while (++i<=NF) {
    if ( split(tolower($i), arr, /#/)>1 ){ for(v in arr) !unq[arr[v]]++;printf comma;
        for (x in unq) {printf (x!="")?hash""x:""; hash="#"; delete unq[x]}}
    else {printf comma""$i; comma=","}}; print ""
}' infile.csv
```