# Remove duplicates from particular columns

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, csv

I have a file in below format, where columns are separated with comma.

```
[1], Value1,   UAC,                 AB
[2.2], Check1, BOH D2A D2A BOH,     SD
[63], name2,   MFB MFB,              k
...
```

I want to remove duplicate values from column (say 3<sup>rd</sup>column) like below:

```
[1], Value1,   UAC,             AB
[2.2], Check1, BOH D2A ,        SD
[63], name2,   MFB,              k
...
```

How to use `uniq` or `AWK` for particular column.

Comment: order of entries after removing supplicates in 3rd column is matter?

Comment: no matter, But contents should be in same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{
    printf $1 FS $2 FS; 
    split($3, arr, / +/); for(val in arr) !uniq_arr[ arr[val] ]++;
    for (key in uniq_arr) { 
        printf (key!="")? SPACE key:""; SPACE=" "; delete uniq_arr[key]
    };
    printf FS $4"\n"
}' infile
```

```
[1], Value1, UAC, AB
[2.2], Check1, D2A BOH, SD
[63], name2, MFB, k
```

- This `split($3, arr, / +/)` splits column#3 into the array `arr` based on space separator (there may one-or-more spaces will be there as separator).
- In `for(val in arr) !uniq_arr[ arr[val] ]++`, we are creating a new array with removed duplicated values taken from array `arr`; so the final values in array `uniq_arr` are only unique values in each column3.
- next we are just printing saved values in `uniq_arr` and delete that key after it printed; note that values of column#1, #2 & #4 were printed separately.

see also:

- [How does awk '!a[$0]++' work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159695/72456)
- [remove duplicated pattern/entries within each field in CSV file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/432151/72456)

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Uniq -f option helps you please check

Comment: Mine question is bit different, that to be check only column3 and make it uniq . Other columns will remain intact

Comment: Waiting for other answers....